# Cannot switch PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4 on Ubutnu 20.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, webserver

I need to switch the PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4 on Ubutnu 20.04. I tried to run the commands below (but without success):

```sh
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

When I open a local webpage with the PHP info `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, the PHP version is still 8.0.3 and not 7.4.

Note that when I execute the command `sudo a2enmod php7.4` I get the following output:

```sh
dan@dan:~$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.4:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
Considering conflict php5 for php7.4:
Enabling module php7.4.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
```

Maybe is that the source of the issue?

Comment: Checkout this, this might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506956/sudo-a2enmod-php5-6-php-v-still-shows-php-7-01-conflict

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that but with no luck :(

Comment: Same issue here,,, Have you solved it ?

Comment: @MohamadPishdad Yes, kind of... I switched to docker :)

Answer (score 10):

Use `update-alternatives` to set the default `php` version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

If you get an error `no alternatives for php`, refer to [my answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410851/153195) to add `php` to `update-alternatives` ( replace `python` by `php`).

Comment: Thanks, that command changes the PHP version on the command line but not on the webserver. Note that the Apache PHP module and the PHP command line binary are two different things: https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php/1190483

Comment: This is a good answer for switching the CLI. On Ubuntu 20.04, I upgraded PHP. Apache was upgraded to 7.4.23 but the CLI was upgraded to 8.0.10. This answer showed me how to switch the CLI back to 7.4.23 which is my goal for both Apache2 and the CLI.

Answer (score 7):

I have found the answer. The problem was that apache was still trying to use php-fpm-8.0 and in order to solve the problem I simply installed the php7.4-fpm and disabled the php8.0-fpm with the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop php8.0-fpm
sudo systemctl disable php8.0-fpm

sudo apt install php7.4-fpm
sudo systemctl start php7.4-fpm
sudo systemctl enable php7.4-fpm

sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, that worked for me too. I used it to enable 7.4 and disable 8.1 which had the same issue:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl start php7.4-fpm
sudo systemctl enable php7.4-fpm
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: After doing this I was still encountering problems. Went to apache2/conf-enabled/ and saw that php8.1-fpm.conf was still enabled because of a typo I made.